# How can I omit this Nil Case

Tags: scala, sorting, functional-programming

I am mucking around with scala implementing some common algorithms. While attempting to recreate a bubble sort I ran into this issue

Here is an implementation of an the inner loop that bubbles the value to the top:

```
def pass(xs:List[Int]):List[Int] = xs match { 
  case Nil => Nil 
  case x::Nil => x::Nil 
  case l::r::xs if(l>r) => r::pass(l::xs)
  case l::r::xs => l::pass(r::xs)
}
```

My issue is with case `Nil => Nil`. I understand that I need this is because I could apply `Nil` to this function. Is there a way to ensure that `Nil` can't be provided as an argument in a manner that would satisfy the compiler so I can eliminate this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List has two subtypes, Nil and ::, so :: represents a list that has at least one element.

```
def pass(xs: ::[Int]):List[Int] = xs match { 
  case x::Nil => x::Nil 
  case l::r::xs if(l>r) => r::pass(new ::(l,xs))
  case l::r::xs => l::pass(new ::(r, xs))
}
```

Comment: Note that this means you'll be unable to apply this function to `List[Int]` values in general, because the compiler usually isn't aware whether any given `List[Int]` will be empty or not at runtime (doing so in general requires solving the Halting Problem). Pattern matching is the mechanism by which a general unknown `List[Int]` value can go down two different branches depending on whether it's `Nil` or a `::[Int]`. That means that if you're passing around lists as `List[Int]`, you'd usually have to pattern match on them every time you call `pass`.

Answer (score 2):

This would roughly correspond to a *refinement* of the original type, where you would write a type whose members were a subset of the initial type.  You would then show that, for every input `x` to your function, that `x` was non  `Nil`.  As this requires a good amount of proof (you can implement this in Coq with dependent types using a *subset* type), the better thing to do in this situation might be to introduce a new type, which was a list having no `Nil` constructor, only a constructor for cons and a single element.

EDIT: As Scala allows you to use subtyping over the List type to enforce this, you can prove it in the type system decidably using that subtype.  This is *still* a proof, in the sense that any type checking corresponds to a proof that the program does indeed inhabit some type, it's just something the compiler can prove completely.

Comment: why the downvote?  I don't see anything wrong with this answer?  Can you point out something technically incorrect in it?  If so I will change or remove it.

Comment: Because you can use the trick proposed by Kim Stebel without resorting to any kind of complex proof...

Comment: @paradigmatic wrong, it still corresponds to a proof in the type system, the proof is via subtyping, so there's still a proof, it's just in a decidable logic.  Still a proof, but I edited my answer to note yours.

Comment: Yes, but it is not a "complex proof". It does not imply dependent types, or a state-of-the-art theorem prover like Coq.

Comment: @paradigmatic okay, that's fair, I don't see "complex proof" in my answer anywhere, but I do see a good amount.  I'll still leave it with the caveat that this morally corresponds to a dependent type which is punted to the deterministic fragment to correspond with it via subtyping.

Answer (score 2):

In that case you can simply play with the `case` clauses order:

```
def pass(xs:List[Int]):List[Int] = xs match { 
  case l::r::xs if(l>r) => r::pass(l::xs)
  case l::r::xs => l::pass(r::xs)
  case xs => xs
}
```

The first two clauses will only match lists with one or more elements. The last clause will match elsewhere.

Comment: I don't see how this precludes Nil being passed in.  The compiler still cannot enforce that Nil be passed as an argument given the reordering.

Comment: It does not preclude it, but allows to "ommit the Nil case" as stated in the question title.

Comment: Perhaps agrees with the title, but does not agree with the statement that the OP wants to "ensure that Nil can't be provided as an argument in a manner that would satisfy the compiler so I can eliminate this case"

Comment: I interpreted the last sentence of the question as a bonus point. I don't think it is off-topic and it can still help some users. I may be wrong.